# как написать такие циклы, в чём секрет?

Tags: javascript

```
77777
7777
777
77
7

55555
4444
333
22
1
```

Comment: `document.write( [5,4,3,2,1].map(e => ("" + e).repeat(e)).join('<br>') )` [Y_Y]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
for (let i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let j = i; j > 0; j-- ) {
        document.write(i)
    }
    document.write('<br>')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let s = '7';
for (let j = 10; j >= 1; j--) {
    document.write(s.repeat(j) + '<br>');
}
```